# To to get the sum of conditional aggregates in an Access form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

I have a table tblBudget, which contains 
ID    ExpenseType   Year   Month   Amount 
11          Hardware      2017    Sep    5000 
11          Software       2017    Oct     2000 
11          Hardware      2016   Jan     1000 
12          Software       2017   Feb     1500

I need to display the expenses by ID, ExpenseType, Year, Month. Hence I created a Group by query

```
Select id,ExpenseType,year,Month,sum (Amount) as sumOfAmount
from  tblBudget
Group by ID,ExpenseType,Year,Month
```

This query works fine, however I need to sum up the total by Total Amount at the bottom of the screen.

On the access form I tried setting the control source as "=sum([Amount])" however it gives me an #error. 
I guess this is due to the fact that I already have sums of Amount in my datasheet. Is there any way to get the grand total in the footer of the form

Comment: What do you mean by 'set the data source'? Do you mean ControlSource property of a textbox?

Comment: Yes sorry I meant control source. Original question edited.

Comment: If [Amount] is not a field in the aggregate query because you are aggregating it, then I expect the fieldname is something like SumOfAmount. Reference that field in the form footer. Why use a form for aggregate data and not a report? Instead of an aggregate query, use report Sorting & Grouping features with aggregate calcs in group and report footers. Report allows display of detail data as well as summary calcs.

Comment: I also tried control source as =sum([sumOfAmount]) but it shows #error. I guess that is because sumOfAmount is already a sum. Unfortunately I cannot use a report because the business requirement is for an interactive form to monitor the costs

Comment: Shouldn't matter that sumOfAmount is an aggregate. It's a field in query and can be referenced. Works for me. How much interactive? A report in ReportView will allow Click events. A report can even be placed on a form.